# Is it possible to get vaccinated while being in Belgium as a foreign student?

Tags: covid-19, eu, belgium, russian-citizens, vaccinations

I am a Russian citizen who plans to spend some time for a research trip in Belgium in spring 2022.

I know that study visas are being issued, but, as I am locally vaccinated and thus without an EU-style vaccination document, I am wondering: would it be possible for a foreign student while in Belgium to get vaccinated locally and thus receive one?

To which extent is it even possible to function in Belgium without a local vaccination confirmation? I find conflicting information, from “absolutely without limits, as long as not visiting public events and museums” to “absolutely everything is closed unless with an EU-accredited vaccine”.

Comment: Non-Belgians who have been registered in Belgium as a student or employee for more than 3 months are eligible to be vaccinated https://www.info-coronavirus.be/en/vaccination/

Comment: *I am locally vaccinated and thus without an EU-style vaccination document* In Spain we regularly do accept medical documents from other countries as evidence of vaccination, in fact you can go to the regional healthcare administration, provide the documents and get an EU DCC! I do not know the administrative requirements (i.e. if you must be a registered resident) though. Be aware that Sputnik-V is not an OMS approved vaccine and so if you only have those no DCC would be issued.

Answer (score 6):

### Receiving a vaccination as a foreigner

As pointed by @Traveller in the comments, yes, you can get vaccinated as soon as you get your BIS number, [which your school will coordinate](https://www.thomasmore.be/en/en/coronavirus-covid-19-english/covid-vaccination-certificates#not). So if you go for J&J, you'll be fully vaccinated within 1 month of arrival at the latest.

### Getting a vaccine certificate

If you got an EMA-approved vaccine (which doesn't include Sputnik V) and the BIS, [you can request](https://www.info-coronavirus.be/en/vaccination/) that your GP validate your vaccine, and you'll get a local vaccine certificate (CST).

### What is possible without a valid certificate

That will depend largely on where you're going to be (Flanders, Wallonia, Brussels or German-speaking community), as additional measures are in place at the regional level. The source I linked below provides the links to the specific regions

On a general level, [you'll be able to](https://www.info-coronavirus.be/en/faq/) (with a face mask when in public spaces):

- Go shopping
- Go to a hair dresser, pedicure, nail salon, etc.
- Go to church (small services)
- Take public transport
- Visit people or have people over